# Generic style to hide or show all the TableRows in Table

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have FlowDocumentScrollViewer that contains a Table and each table row contains two cells which contains some text. Here is my xaml.

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Table
                    CellSpacing="1.2">
                    <Table.Columns>
                        <TableColumn />
                        <TableColumn />
                    </Table.Columns>
                    <TableRowGroup>
                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Instrument Serial Number:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding InstrumentSerialNumber}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Plate Name:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding PlateName}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Date of Run:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding DateOfRun}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="User Name of Run Initiator:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding UserName}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Thermal Cycling Protocol Name:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding ThermalCyclerName}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Thermal Cycling Definition:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding ThermalCyclerDefinition}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Bar Code:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding BarCode}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="SuperMix Type:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding SuperMixName}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Number Of Wells Generated:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding NumberOfWells}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Number Of Wells Read:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding NumberOfWellsRead}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Oil Name:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding OilName}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Total Plate Run Time:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding TotalPlateRunTime}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Errors:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding Errors}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Software Version:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding SoftwareVersion}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>

                        <TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                            <TableCell
                                TextAlignment="Center">
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="Firmware Version:"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell>
                                <Paragraph
                                    FontWeight="Bold">
                                    <Run
                                        Text="{Binding FirmwareVersion}"></Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRowHelper:BRTableRow>
                    </TableRowGroup>
                </Table>
            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Please see TableRowHelper:BRTableRow which is a custom control where I created a dependency property for visibility to hide or show a Table Row. Here is the code.

```
public class BRTableRow : TableRow
    {
        public Visibility IsRowVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return (Visibility)GetValue(RowVisibleDependencyProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(RowVisibleDependencyProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RowVisibleDependencyProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsRowVisible", typeof(Visibility), typeof(BRTableRow), new PropertyMetadata());
    }
```

Is there a generic style trigger that I can apply on visibility of each table row. For example if the text i.e. {Binding InstrumentSerialNumber}. If this text is empty I want to collapse the visibility. So on and so forth. But I don't want to create multiple styles. I just want 1 style that I can use on all Table Rows. Any ideas. Please help.

Comment: What about a converter on `Visibility` that uses your string as a parameter ?

Comment: Yes that works. I was thinking the same thing,. Can you please post a sample code for that.